# Can FASTA data be submitted directly into eCTD submission to the FDA?

Tags: fasta

We are getting sequence data from microbiota samples as part of a FDA submission identifying changes in Micobiota from skin samples over time and compared with different treatments.  the data will be first presented in FASTA formate then analyzed for OTUs and differences.  The submission has to follow eCTD format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.